# Facroring out a constant from the first kind Bessel function's argument

Tags: summation, bessel-functions

I have a Bessel function of the first kind, whose series expansion is:

$ J_{\alpha} (t) = \displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+\alpha+1)}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)^{2m+\alpha}.$

In my specific application, variable $t$ can be decomposed as $t=\frac{xy}{z}$, yielding

$ J_{\alpha} \left(\frac{xy}{z}\right) = \displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+\alpha+1)}\left(\frac{xy}{2z}\right)^{2m+\alpha}. \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (1)$

I would like to know if it is possible rewrite the above expression in the form

$\Xi\left(\frac{y}{z}\right)J_{\alpha} (x)$.

My guess is to rewrite (1) as

$ J_{\alpha} \left(\frac{xy}{z}\right) = \displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+\alpha+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m+\alpha}\left(\frac{y}{z}\right)^{2m}\left(\frac{y}{z}\right)^{\alpha} = \left(\frac{y}{z}\right)^{\alpha}\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+\alpha+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m+\alpha}\left(\frac{y}{z}\right)^{2m}$.

Moreover, under the assumption that $|\frac{y}{z}|<1$, I would like to know if it is possible to factor out the sum of the geometric series $\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{y^2}{z^2}\right)^m$ as

$ J_{\alpha} \left(\frac{xy}{z}\right) = (\frac{y}{z})^{\alpha}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{y^2}{z^2}}\right)\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+\alpha+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m+\alpha}$.

Is it correct ? I have doubts on the last step.

Comment: No. If this was possible then $\Xi(t) \equiv \frac{J_\alpha(tx)}{J_\alpha(x)}$ would not depend on $x$. This again would mean that $J_\alpha(x)$ would have to be a powerlaw in $x$ which it isn't. A simple way to disprove such a relation is to take, say, $\alpha=1$ and $t=1$ and try different values of $x$ numerically and you will see that that ratio is not constant.

Comment: The way you want to factor out the geometric sum is totally invalid.

Comment: @Gary Yeah, I have found out why, and a discussion on the specific issue can be found in this related thread:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4252770/is-displaystyle-sum-i-0-infty-fi-xgi-y-s-g-sum-i-0-inftyfi-x?noredirect=1&lq=1
Anyway, I leave the question open in case someone figures out a way to correctly factor out the expression in the form I need.