# Is $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} f(i,x)g(i,y)=S_g\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}f(i,x)$ true, if $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}g(i,y)$ converges to $S_g$?

Tags: summation

Let us suppose to have a summation in the form

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} f(i,x)g(i,y)$$

If $ \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}g(i,y) $ converges to  $ S_g$, does the following expression holds?

$$ \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} f(i,x)g(i,y) = S_g \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} f(i,x)$$

The original problem arises from:
[Facroring out a constant from the first kind Bessel function's argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4252101/facroring-out-a-constant-from-the-first-kind-bessel-functions-argument)

Comment: Take series with just two non-zero terms and see what happens.

Comment: No, because the index $i$ in both the $g$ and $f$ is the *same*. If you're talking about getting the $g$ part out, it can happen only if the original summation was $\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty f(i,x)g(j,y)$, which would equal $S_g \sum_{i=0}^\infty f(i,x)$.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thank you! Any insight on why it does not hold in the case the two functions share the same index ?

Comment: @davideAlbertini Because there aren't enough terms. For example, when I multiply $(x_1+y_1)(x_2+y_2)$, then I get $x_1y_1+x_1y_2+x_2y_1+x_2y_2$, so the indices are in the pattern $(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)$, so *both* the indices are varying from $1$ to $2$. Just having $x_1y_1+x_2y_2$ is not correct, as you can see. The missing terms aren't captured in $\sum_{i=0}^\infty f(i,x)g(i,y)$.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks, so I guess in this case $ \sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} f(i, x)g(i,y) = S_g\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} f(i, x) + \sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{j=0, j\neq i}^{+\infty} f(i, x)g(j,y)$

Comment: @davideAlbertini If you change the $+$ sign to a $-$ sign on the RHS, then perfect! You have it in place.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yeah, of course ! Thanks a lot for your time. I will post the answer below!

Comment: @davideAlbertini Thanks, I'll follow this post so I can get to know when it is done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When considering the summation

$ \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} f(i,x)g(i,y) $

it is not possible to extract a term $S_g=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}g(i,y) $ from the expression above, as suggested in the question.
This is due to the fact that $ S_g\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} f(i,x)$ has more terms than $ \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} f(i,x)g(i,y) $.

A dummy example with the summation index $i=1,2$ would clarify the problem.
Let us consider

$ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{2} x_iy_i =x_1y_1+x_2y_2 $.

The above expression is different from

$ S_y\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{2} x_i=(y_1+y_2)(x_1+x_2)= x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_1y_2+x_2y_1$.

Thus a correct relation is

$ \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} f(i,x)g(i,y) = S_y\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} f(i,x) - \sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{j=0,j\neq i}^{+\infty}f(i,x)g(j,y)$